# How can I duplicate the same row but with different information in a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
table = pd.DataFrame({'Range': ["A", "B", "C", "A"],'First Name': ["W","X","Y", "Z"], 'ID': [1,2,3,4]})
```

[image: Initial state of dataframe]

I want to replicate the same row if in the "Level" column I have the text "A", but in the "Activity" column add the text "Monitoring" and "Informant", something like this:

[image: Desired output of data transformation example]

I tried to make the duplicate with this code

```
columns_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=["NO ID","Level", "Name", "Activity"])

row_modified = []

for index, row in table.iterrows():
rang = row['Range']
f_name= row['First Name']
n_id = row['ID']

columns_new.loc[index, "NO ID"] = n_id
columns_new.loc[index, "Level"] = rang
columns_new.loc[index, "Name"] = f_name

    if  rang == "A":
        row_modified.append(row)
        row_modified.append(row)
    else:
        row_modified.append(row)

column_new2 = pd.DataFrame(row_modified)
column_new2
```

[image: Dataframe result of code so far]

But I don't know how to add the texts I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mapping dict:

```
d = {'A': ['Monitoring', 'Informant']}

out = (table.assign(Activity=table['Range'].map(d).fillna('Assistant'))
            .explode('Activity'))
print(out)

# Output
  Range First Name  ID    Activity
0     A          W   1  Monitoring
0     A          W   1   Informant
1     B          X   2   Assistant
2     C          Y   3   Assistant
3     A          Z   4  Monitoring
3     A          Z   4   Informant
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```
s = pd.Series(['Monitoring', 'Informant'], index=['A', 'A'], name='Activity')

(table.merge(s, left_on='Range', right_index=True, how='left')
      .fillna({'Activity': 'Assistant'})
)
```

Output:

```
  Range First Name  ID    Activity
0     A          W   1  Monitoring
0     A          W   1   Informant
1     B          X   2   Assistant
2     C          Y   3   Assistant
3     A          Z   4  Monitoring
3     A          Z   4   Informant
```